# Terraform override file execute for a specific Jenkins parameter

Tags: terraform

I have a _override.tf file which overrides the no of instances running for an aws service. I want to scale down the instances to zero whenever I choose a particular Jenkins parameter in the build. But the override.tf will execute always irrespective of whether I select that option or not which I don't want. How can we configure it so that the override file only overrides when the particular Jenkins parameter is selected?

I tried the override file but it overrides for every build

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following variable:

```hcl
variable "instances_count" {
  type        = number
  default     = 10
  description = "Number of instances to create."
}
```

#### [Using variables in the command line](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name)

You should be able to override it using the `-var` option when running the `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` commands:

```bash
terraform apply -var="instances_count=0"
```

#### [Using TF_VAR_XXXXX environment variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name)

You can also run the `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` commands with environment variable `TF_VAR_instances_count` set to `0`